# trying to import dll in netbeans c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, dll

I have some problem to include a the FFTw3 library into my project. This is the first time I touch dll's so I'm rather sure that will be something simple that is missing ...

What I did till now is:

- set Build/C++ Compiler/Include Directories - and set it to the lib folder
- set Bujld/Linker/Additional Library Directories - and added the same lib folder

Afterwards I tried to run the demo script below.

```
#include <fftw3.h>
int main(void) // Tutorial code from http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html
{

 int N = 10;

 fftw_complex in[N], out[N];
 fftw_plan p;

 p = fftw_create_plan(N, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

 fftw_one(p, in, out);

 fftw_destroy_plan(p);  

 }
```

Whereby it found the headerfile fftw3.h and was ok upto (runs if the rest is commented out)

```
p = fftw_create_plan(N, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

There it states:

> main.cpp:19:57: error: ‘fftw_create_plan’ was not declared in this
>   scope

I was looking trough the net and got quit confused. Do I also need .lib files, are they created from the .dev files and if how so? (they look rather the same to me, but than again, I don't know anything about this topic)

So I was wondering if anybody of you has the knowledge and is willing to help me to make it run ...

thx
magu_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the include directory to the path where your header files (eg `fftw3.h`) are. To check if your header is set by *ctrl + click* on the include.

Next set the library like this:

- Project Properties, **`Build -> Linker`**
- Additional Library Directory: Set the *directroypath* where your `.lib` or `.dll` is - *not* a file
- Libraries: **`[...] -> Add Library`** and type the *name* of your library there, eg. if the library is named `libFFTw3.dll` write only `FFTw3`.

Use `Add Library File` instead if you want to specify a full filename.

---

### Edit:

**Windows (using MinGW):**

Download: http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

used code for this example (it's an example from the website):

```
fftw_complex *in, *out;
fftw_plan p;

size_t N = 3;

in = ( fftw_complex* ) fftw_malloc(sizeof (fftw_complex ) * N);
out = ( fftw_complex* ) fftw_malloc(sizeof (fftw_complex ) * N);
p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */

fftw_destroy_plan(p);
fftw_free(in);
fftw_free(out);
```

Setting up NetBeans:

1. Open Project Buildproperties ( **`Properties -> Build`** )
2. **`C++ Compiler -> Includes directories -> [...] -> Add`**, select path where you unpacked the library
3. Go to **`Linker`**
   a. **`Additional Library Direcotries -> [...] -> Add`**, select path where you unpacked the library (not the library!)
   b. **`Libraries -> [...] -> Add Library`**, write *`fftw3-3`* there and press Ok

On Linux the steps are the same, but you have to build the library before.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your Answer. I did everthing ecxept the last point (which I did now) but unfortnatly without success. It still doesn't find the fftw_create_plan.

Comment: Do you have to use a namespace? is this function available in the header?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. There is nothing written in the header file or in the manual. It did try "using namespace std;" without success however.

Comment: I mean, is the `fftw_create_paln()` function available in the `fftw3.h` header? Or is this library using a own namespace?

Comment: btw. your example seems to for fftw2, but your library is fftw3 - can this lead to this problem?

Comment: One moment, i download the lib and check how to use it.

Comment: Autsch. Yes you're right. This did fix the problem. I was to lazy to navigate trough the fftw site and used google to get there. This will teach me a lesson to first take a proper look at URL's... Thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

**fftw_create_plan() is out of date in fftw3**

fftw3.h
manual is here

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs

please use the new syntax  **fftw_plan_dft_1d()**  to create plan